# How can I manage Date if it have 24:00 as time?

Tags: c#, .net, date

I have some data coming from an XML document, such as 2012-12-06T24:00.

The problem is when I try to convert it : 24:00 doesnt exist. So :

```
DateTime.Parse(myDateTimeString).Hour
```

give to me this Exception: `System.FormatException: The DateTime represented by the string is not supported in calendar System.Globalization.GregorianCalendar.`

How can I fix it?

The solution I think about is to replace (string) T24 with T00, which looks horrible...

Comment: Do you have control over the code that is creating that DateTime?  I would fix it that side instead of the parsing side.

Comment: Of course not...it is a XML taken from a internet service :)

Comment: Is `2012-12-06T24:00` the same as `2012-12-06T00:00` or `2012-12-07T00:00`?  The first treats midnight as midnight, the second advances to the next day.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`DateTime` cannot handle this. You have to "sanitize" your string before calling `Parse` and handle the overflow (depending on what "24:00" actually means):

```
DateTime date = DateTime.Parse(myDateTimeString.Replace("T24:00", "T00:00"));

if (myDateTimeString.Contains("T24:00"))
{
    date = date.AddDays(1);
}
```

**EDIT**: added the "overflow"-part.

Comment: Although the OP doesn't mention the possibility of a longer time string, I would still be inclined to code for it.  It's a bit embarassing when you find you've fixed up "2012-01-01T13:24:00".

Comment: `T24:00` means midnight at the *end* of the day